# Double encrypting 2048 RSA?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have a problem. I'm trying to write a secure chat server using RSA encryption. I'm trying to double encrypt so a each client knows that messages can only come from the other client(s) and they are the only ones that can read the messages. The thing is, when I'm trying to double encrypt even a 1-character long message, the resulting first encrypted byte array is 256 bytes long, and of course, you can't encrypt that a second time with another key because its too long. My question is, how can I double encrypt with the code below? In theory, I generate two separate key pairs, and then encrypt a string with the public key of one, and then the private key of another, and do vice-versa for decrypting the string. Trust me, I've tried.

```
package client.crypto;

import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class CryptoUtils {

private static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";

public static KeyPair getKeyPair() {
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = null;
    try {
        keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      keyGen.initialize(2048);
      final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    return key;
}

 public static byte[] encrypt(String text, Key key) {
        byte[] cipherText = null;
        try {
          final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
          cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cipherText;
      }

 public static String decrypt(String text, Key key) {
        byte[] dectyptedText = null;
        try {
          final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
          dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new String(dectyptedText);
      }
 public static byte[] decryptToBytes(String text, Key key) {
        byte[] dectyptedText = null;
        try {
          final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
          dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dectyptedText;
      }

 public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] bytes, Key key) {
        byte[] cipherText = null;
        try {
          final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
          cipherText = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cipherText;
      }

 public static String decrypt(byte[] bytes, Key key) {
        byte[] dectyptedText = null;
        try {
          final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
          dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(bytes);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new String(dectyptedText);
      }

 public static byte[] decryptToBytes(byte[] bytes, Key key) {
        byte[] dectyptedText = null;
        try {
          final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
          dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(bytes);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dectyptedText;
      }



}
```

Comment: By "double-encrypt" do you mean encrypt and sign? Either way, all these ciphers have block sizes, encrypting one byte will have the same output size as encrypting ten.

Comment: Usually, messages are not encrypted with RSA directly. You generate a one-time-use symmetric key (like AES) to encrypt the message with. And then transmit that session key encrypted (and optionally signed) with RSA.

Comment: "they are the only ones that can read the messages" - That's already true unless your private key was compromised.  "messages can only come from the other client(s)" - The only way to achieve that is to establish a chain of trust to verify the authenticity of the other party's public key.

Comment: @Thilo I had a hunch that was the case, but I couldn't find anything on that. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Yes, I know that, don't worry. This is nothing serious that I am creating, rather me just trying to expand my java knowledge! Thanks for the concern though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Thilo I'm wondering, do you think creating a 2048-bit key pair and then a 1024-bit key pair work? I could encrypt a string with a 1024-bit key, and then encrypt that with the 2048-bit key, and vice versa for decrypting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements are reasonable, but your proposed solution is fundamentally flawed and should be abandoned.

You should go back to your requirements and seek to achieve those requirements using the standard techniques and APIs.

You should not try to invent your own cryptography methodology. It is difficult to get right and you are much more likely to create a truly secure system if you follow the standard practices. Some thoughts on how you should approach your requirements:

1. You need to establish some way to managed/distribute certificates in such a way that you can establish trust between the entities that are communicating. Usually, certificates (which are basically signed public keys that have been signed by someone that you trust) are used and distributed freely.
2. To allow verification of the identity of the sender (and also that the message has not been modified), you will use a digital signature (not encryption). What happens here is that a "digest" or "hash" is computed over the contents of the message, resulting in a relatively small number of bytes regardless of the length of the message. The digest is signed with the sender's private key. The sender's public key can be used to validate the signature.
3. To allow the message to be read only by the intended recipients, you will use encryption. What happens here is that a random, single-use passphrase is generated and used to encrypt the message. The passphrase is encrypted using the intended recipient's public key. The recipient's private key is required in order to recover the passphrase, which then allows the message to be decrypted. You can encrypt the same copy of the message for multiple recipients simply by encrypting the passphrase multiple times.
4. You need to pick a message format, which allows for parsing the signed, encrypted message to pick out the various parts. An example would be CMS (cryptographic message format).

As you have found out, RSA is good for encrypting relatively small amounts of data. I will also note that encrypting with RSA is much much slower than encrypting with a symmetric algorithm such as AES. The encryption community has worked for decades to come up with secure and performant solutions, such as a way to leverage the performance of symmetric encryption (e.g., AES) while having the trust pattern (no shared secret) of asymmetric encryption (e.g., RSA).

Comment: Thanks! This will help me a ton with future projects.